# Optimizing generic AddDistinct extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Can I write these functions more efficient?

```
public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, params ICollection<T>[] collections)
{
    (from collection in collections from item in collection where !source.Contains(item) select item).ForEach(source.Add);
}

public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, params ICollection<T>[] collections)
{
    collections.ForEach(collection => collection.Where(predicate).Where(item => !source.Contains(item)).ForEach(source.Add));
}

public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    items.Where(item => !source.Contains(item)).ForEach(source.Add);
}

public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, params T[] items)
{
    items.Where(predicate).Where(x => !source.Contains(x)).ForEach(source.Add);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Except` method:

```
public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, params ICollection<T>[] collections)
{
    var itemsToAdd = collections.SelectMany(x => x).Where(predicate).Except(source).ToArray();
    itemsToAdd.ForEach(source.Add));
}

public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, params ICollection<T>[] collections)
{
    var itemsToAdd = collections.SelectMany(x => x).Where(predicate).Except(source).ToArray();
    itemsToAdd.ForEach(source.Add));
}

public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    var itemsToAdd = items.Except(source).ToArray();
    itemsToAdd.ForEach(source.Add));
}

public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, params T[] items)
{
    var itemsToAdd = items.Where(predicate).Except(source).ToArray();
    itemsToAdd.ForEach(source.Add));
}
```

Note that because `Where` and `Except` have deferred and streamed execution, you need the `ToArray()` call to ensure the enumeration of `source` is complete before you add anything to it (since a collection can't be modified while it's being enumerated).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using e.g. a hashset you can do much better than `O(N*M)`.

Comment: The built-in Enumerable.Except method probably uses a HashSet already (or something similar), and is much more intuitive to use...

Comment: @Thomas: I dunno, I think [Svish's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405903/generic-adddistinct-extension-method/5406201#5406201) is a lot simpler than the original code.  And unlike `Except`, his answer is easy to extend to many collections.

Answer (score 2):

Using `HashSet<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` you can do it more efficient I think. The HashSet is efficient at keeping track of duplicates, and you only need to go through the source once to load them into the set. And unless I'm mistaken, I think both `ICollection<T>` and `T[]` are `IEnumerable<T>`s?

```
public static void AddDistinct<T>(this ICollection<T> source, params IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>(source);
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if(set.Add(item))
            source.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Not sure what you need those predicate versions for though. Can't you just filter your items before you add them?

Comment: I agree, I can use a filter before.